# Is Dictionary the best way to record presence or absence of a key

Tags: c#, dictionary, key

Apologies if this has already been asked elsewhere, but I couldn't find it.

I want to store a set of strings in .NET, in such as way that they can be easily and quickly looked up to find if the key is stored or not.

I could just use a List<string> and enumerate the list every time I need to search, but obviously that linear search is quite inefficient.

So my next thought is to use a Dictionary<string, object> and query that each time, which should hopefully result in some cool string hashing and faster search times. However, I'm not actually storing anything in the "object" part of the dictionary so it seems like there might be an inefficiency there.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: List<string> has a Contains method so you wouldn't need to enumerate it to find a match

Comment: @KAJ Guess what `Contains` does internally. ;-)

Comment: @KAJ - looks like the best answer is to use a HashSet, but just wondering - would the List.Contains method execute in O(1), or would it just do a linear search behind the scenes like my version would? (I imagine the latter, as List<T> works on any type, not just those that can be ordered and hashed)

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Does it order pizza for you while you wait for it to complete? Well it should! My philosophy is, why make programs faster and more efficient when you can just make the wait more 'desirable'!

Comment: Contains is an O(n) where n is Count operation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx. @Konrad Rudolph yes I knew that but I was more pointing out there's no point in manually implementing an enumeration in this case ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for a `HashSet<string>`, which provides the same O(1) performance of a dictionary, but without those pesky values.

Answer (score 2):

`HashSet<string>` for unordered sets or
`SortedSet<string>` if order is importent.

Answer (score 0):

If your dictionary object is being used by multiple threads, ConcurrentDictionary(Of TKey, TValue) is be a better choice.